# JavaScript - Concatenate a value within variable

Tags: javascript, concatenation, string-concatenation

I know that this is somewhat, very basic question, but..
I have to create a cypress element, for which I have to concatenate a value between variables.

Like I have this value

```
const value = "100 - 299"
```

and I have to print a value within a string, i.e.

```
cy.get('[data-value="100 - 299"]')
```

I am trying everything but unable to do so.
Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Try backticks. Within them you can `[data-value="${value}"] `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)  - also called backticks

```
cy.get(`[data-value="${value}"]`)
```

Comment: I just want to add that template literals work in most browsers, but there are older versions of browsers that it will not work in. And if you run a development company like me, you'll know that clients do not care that their customers use Internet Explorer from the early 2000s, they WILL blame the devs! https://caniuse.com/template-literals

Comment: @Nerdi.org If you need that, you can use Babel

Answer (score 1):

You could consider concatenation.

```
const value = "100 - 299"

cy.get('[data-value="' + value + '"]')
```

Or template literals ( check compatability: https://caniuse.com/template-literals )

```
cy.get(`[data-value="${value}"]`)
```

Or pre-concatenation:

```
const value = "100 - 299"
const fullstring = '[data-value="' + value + '"]'
cy.get(fullstring)
```